# Upload multiple images on Amazon S3 using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, multer-s3

I am trying to upload images to amazon s3. However req.files is still undefined. I don't understand where is my code going wrong. The images are sent from Angular frontend. 'artFileLocations' is array of files in FormData. How do I fix this?

```
const router            = require('express').Router()
const AWS               = require('aws-sdk')
const multer            = require('multer');
const multerS3          = require('multer-s3');

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

// Unique name of aws s3 bucket created
const myBucket = 'nish.images';

// Multer upload (Use multer-s3 to save directly to AWS instead of locally)
var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: myBucket,
    // Set public read permissions
    acl: 'public-read',
    // Set key/ filename as original uploaded name
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
  })
})


router.post('/', upload.array('artFileLocations', 3), function(req, res) {
    console.log('Reaching addPainting')
    console.log(req.body, req.files)
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the angular code that sends the files? Also what do you get when you console.log `req.headers`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.

but can you update your HTML file like this:

```
<input type="file" name="artFileLocations" multiple>
```

If you already update your HTML file, then I think you don't face any other error.

Comment: I have that already, that is not the issue.

Comment: can you put `console.log(file)` in `key function` and tell me `log`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try uploading single file and check whether your *req.files* is working or not. I also encountered this error where the multiple file upload was not working. So, check if the *req.files* is working for single file upload.